# Как открыть ссылку браузером chrome сразу в режиме эмуляции мобильного устройства, с заданным разрешением

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Занимаюсь ручным тестированием верстки и приходиться по 200 раз открывать девтулс и выбирать там нужное разрешение.
Как на java реализовать эту задумку, типа чтобы вставить в метод ссылку и при запуске открывался хром уже с указанным пресетом, к примеру 960х1024

Answer (score 0):

```
@Test
public void mobileTest() {

    Map<String, Object> deviceMetrics = new HashMap<>();
    deviceMetrics.put("width", 960);
    deviceMetrics.put("height", 1024);
    deviceMetrics.put("pixelRatio", 2.0);
    Map<String, Object> mobileEmulation = new HashMap<>();
    mobileEmulation.put("deviceMetrics", deviceMetrics);
    mobileEmulation.put("userAgent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 8.0.0;" +
                        "Pixel 2 XL Build/OPD1.170816.004) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) " +
                        "Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Mobile Safari/537.36");
    ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
    chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("mobileEmulation", mobileEmulation);
    driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);

    driver.get("https://yandex.ru/");

    String title = "expect_result";
    Assert.assertEquals(title, driver.getTitle());
}
```